# Several WinRT functions fail on Xbox, but not on Windows 10

Tags: javascript, c#, uwp, winrt-xaml

I am working on an upgraded version of the installed portion of a hosted app for Xbox. We're moving away from using the old jsproj type and implementing a new project that uses XAML. It's a simple construction with one page holding a Webview, which will show content for the hosted portion of the app.

In any case, I noticed something strange with WinRT when I tested the hosted portion in this new app. We have a lot of JavaScript utilizing WinRT, but some of it is not behaving as expected. I have found at least two functions that are failing with the following errors.

Error 1 (JavaScript):

```
  try {
    const applicationView = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.getForCurrentView();
    applicationView.setDesiredBoundsMode(
      Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewBoundsMode.useCoreWindow,
    );
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e); // Element not found
  }
```

Error 2 (JavaScript):

```
try {
  this.control = Windows.Media.SystemMediaTransportControls.getForCurrentView();
  this.control.isEnabled = true;
  this.control.isFastForwardEnabled = true;
  this.control.isNextEnabled = true;
  this.control.isPauseEnabled = true;
  this.control.isPlayEnabled = true;
  this.control.isPreviousEnabled = true;
  this.control.isRecordEnabled = true;
  this.control.isRewindEnabled = true;
  this.control.isStopEnabled = true;
  this.control.isChannelUpEnabled = true;
  this.control.isChannelDownEnabled = true;
  this.control.playbackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.playing;
  this.control.onbuttonpressed = this.onButtonPressed;
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
  /*
    Invalid window handle. Could not find an appropriate view to be associated 
    with this instance of the MediaPlaybackControl. Please make sure that a view
    has been initialized.
  */
}
```

These same methods do work in C#:

```
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
using Windows.Media;
...
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView()
            .SetDesiredBoundsMode(
                ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseCoreWindow
            );
        this.control = SystemMediaTransportControls
            .GetForCurrentView();
    }
    // code is happy
```

Here are my target and min versions in use:

```
Target version: Windows 10, version 2004 (10.0; build 19041)
Minimum version: Windows 10, version 1809 (10.0; build 17763)
```

I also tried downgrading the target version to:

```
Target version: Windows 10, version 1903 (10.0; build 18362)
Minimum version: Windows 10, version 1809 (10.0; build 17763)
```

What is very odd is that these errors do not occur when I run this same app with the same hosted content on Windows 10. Still, the errors do occur when I launch the application onto an Xbox One or Xbox Series S|X. I guess that Windows 10 is using a different runtime version than what is used on Xbox, but downgrading target versions didn't help either.

What causes these errors, and is there a way to fix them?

**Note:** We can live without the call to get the application view, but we need the client to handle listening for button presses from `SystemMediaTransportControls`. The goal here is to launch the installed portion of the app first and work on updating the JavaScript for the hosted portion in a later phase of work, but it seems like there is not a clear 1:1 between the old version of this project and the new regarding how WinRt works.

Comment: From where do you make the call to the SystemMediaTransportControls.getForCurrentView()? It needs to be done in a UI-thread. I make the call in the constructor in a class derived from Page.

Comment: This is happening on the hosted portion of the app (in JavaScript). To my knowledge though, there is no way to run it explicitly on the UI thread when called from the browser inside the webview?

Comment: Could you share more code that you call above method, Does it call in the JavaScript?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Yes. It is called inside JavaScript. Part of the mystery here is that it works in C# but not in JavaScript, but only when running on an Xbox One, Series X, or Series S. These methods work in both C# and JavaScript when running on Windows 10.

Comment: BTW, I updated the question to show actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview?view=winrt-20348), by default, WebView content is hosted on UI thread in the desktop device family, and off the UI thread on all other devices (Xbox One, Series X, or Series S, ...). Therefore, when other than the default is needed, we could create a WebView instance outside XAML using a  WebViewExecutionMode value we need. For example:

```
 var webView = new WebView(WebViewExecutionMode.SameThread);            
        webView.Source = new Uri("https://...");    
        WebViewParent.Child = webView; //assuming WebViewParent is present in XAML
```

Based on my testings, the errors did occur when I had created the WebView instance using WebViewExecutionMode.SeparateThread,  but not when I had used WebViewExecutionMode.SameThread or WebViewExecutionMode.SeparateProcess.

Comment: Sure enough, this does work. However, I discovered that changing the threading model breaks other code I wrote that must be called from the UI thread (C#-side). In any case, I am marking this as the answer because it did resolve the issue even if it created other headaches for me.